# Finding the longest word ArrayList /Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, if-statement, arraylist

I want to write a method which finds the longest String (word). The output should be the longest word in case of two words with the same lenght the output should be: "More than one longest word".

I used ArrayList and almost had a solution, but something goes wrong. The case is that I have a problem when two words have the same lenght.
The output is :
More than one longest word
More than one longest word
14 incrementation is the longest word

Please check out piece of my code and help me to find the answer :)

```
public class LongestWord {
public static void main(String[] args) {


    ArrayList<String> wordsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    wordsList.add("december");
    wordsList.add("california");
    wordsList.add("cat");
    wordsList.add("implementation");
    wordsList.add("incrementation");


    int largestString = wordsList.get(0).length();
    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < wordsList.size(); i++) {
        if (wordsList.get(i).length() > largestString) {
            largestString = wordsList.get(i).length();
            index = i;

        }else if(wordsList.get(i).length() == largestString){
            largestString = wordsList.get(i).length();
            index = i;
            System.out.println("More than one longest word");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(largestString +" " + wordsList.get(index) +" is the longest word ");


}
```

}

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Beware: `String#length` fails with most characters. Example: [`System.out.println( "".length() ) ;`](https://ideone.com/gA4hRF)  ➔  2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact is that you can't tell what the biggest word until you have iterated the whole list.

So iterate on the list

- if word is bigger than previous largest size : clear list and save word
- if word has same size as largest size : save word
- if word is smaller : nothing

```
List<String> wordsList = Arrays.asList(
        "december", "california", "cat",
        "implementation", "incremntation");

int maxLength = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

List<String> largestStrings = new ArrayList<>();
for (String s : wordsList) {
    if (s.length() > maxLength) {
        maxLength = s.length();
        largestStrings.clear();
        largestStrings.add(s);
    } else if (s.length() == maxLength) {
        largestStrings.add(s);
    }
}

if (largestStrings.size() > 1) {
    System.out.println("More than one longest word");
    System.out.println(largestStrings);
} else {
    System.out.println(largestStrings.get(0) + " is the longest word");
}
```

Gives

```
More than one longest word
[implementation, incrementation]
```

Comment: It can be done in one loop. `int maxLength = 0; List<String> largestStrings = new ArrayList<>(); for (String s : wordsList) { if (s.length() > maxLength) { maxLength = s.length(); largestStrings.clear(); largestStrings.add(s); } else if (s.length() == maxLength) { largestStrings.add(s); }}`

Answer (score 0):

azro is right. You can figure out the problem using two iteration. I m not sure but the code below works

```
for (int i = 0; i < wordsList.size(); i++) {
    if (wordsList.get(i).length() > largestString) {
        largestString = wordsList.get(i).length();
        index = i;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < wordsList.size(); i++) {
    if (wordsList.get(index).length() == wordsList.get(i).length()) {
        System.out.println("More than one longest word");
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with one loop iteration. Storing the longest word(s) as you go.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Collection<String> words = Arrays.asList(
                "december", "california", "cat",
                "implementation", "incrementation");

        final Collection<String> longestWords = findLongestWords(words);

        if (longestWords.size() == 1) {
            System.out.printf("The longest word is: %s\n", longestWords.iterator().next());
        } else if (longestWords.size() > 1) {
            System.out.printf("More than one longest word. The longest words are: %s\n", longestWords);
        }
    }

    private static final Collection<String> findLongestWords(final Collection<String> words) {
        // using a Set, so that duplicate words are stored only once.
        final Set<String> longestWords = new HashSet<>();

        // remember the current length of the longest word
        int lengthOfLongestWord = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        // iterate over all the words
        for (final String word : words) {
            // the length of this word is longer than the previously though longest word. clear the list and update the longest length.
            if (word.length() > lengthOfLongestWord) {
                lengthOfLongestWord = word.length();
                longestWords.clear();
            }

            // the length of this word is currently though to be the longest word, add it to the Set.
            if (word.length() == lengthOfLongestWord) {
                longestWords.add(word);
            }
        }

        // return an unmodifiable Set containing the longest word(s)
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(longestWords);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents to make it done in the single loop. Can be improved further.

```
ArrayList<String> wordsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    wordsList.add("december");
    wordsList.add("california");
    wordsList.add("cat");
    wordsList.add("implementation");
    wordsList.add("incrementation");

    String result;
    int length = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();

    for(String word: wordsList){

        if(word.length() >= length) {
            length = word.length();

            if (map.containsKey(String.valueOf(word.length())) || map.containsKey( "X" + word.length())) {
                map.remove(String.valueOf(word.length()));
                map.put("X" + word.length(), word);
            } else {
                map.put(String.valueOf(word.length()), word);
            }

        }
    }

     result = map.get(String.valueOf(length)) == null ? "More than one longest word" :
             map.get(String.valueOf(length)) + " is the longest word";

    System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code to suggest a different approach to the problem. Honestly, I hope you'll find it fascinating and helpful.
There are two different fashion of it, one that doesn't care about finding more than one longest word (it stamps just the first one - but you can change it as you prefer), and the other one that does.

First solution:

`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class LongestWord {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        List<String> wordsList = new ArrayList<>();
        wordsList.add("december");
        wordsList.add("california");
        wordsList.add("cat");
        wordsList.add("implementation");
        wordsList.add("incrementation");

        wordsList.stream()
            .max(LongestWord::compare)
            .ifPresent(a -> System.out.println(a.toUpperCase() + " is the longest word with length of: " + a.length()));

}

    private static int compare(String a1, String b1) {
       return a1.length() - b1.length();
    }

}
```

`

Second solution:

`

```
public class LongestWord {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        List<String> wordsList = new ArrayList<>();
        wordsList.add("december");
        wordsList.add("california");
        wordsList.add("cat");
        wordsList.add("implementation");
        wordsList.add("incrementation");

        int max_length = wordsList.stream()
                .max(LongestWord::compare)
                .map(String::length).orElse(0);

        List<String> finalWordsList = wordsList.stream()
                .filter(word -> word.length() == max_length)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        if (finalWordsList.size() > 1) {
            System.out.println("More than one longest word");
        } else {
            System.out.println(finalWordsList.get(0) + " is the longest word");
        }

    }

    private static int compare(String a1, String b1) {
      return a1.length() - b1.length();
    }

}
```

`

Comment: The comparison function can be simplified to just `return a1.length() - b1.length();`.

Comment: You are right (and I suck so bad at coding)! Thank you for the comment, I have edited my code. @RotoRa

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach. I am using a set to hold the results as there is no reason to include duplicate words if they exist.

- iterate over the words
- if the current word length is `> maxLength`, clear the set and add the word, and update `maxLength`
- if equal to the maxLength, just add the word.

```
List<String> wordsList = List.of("december", "implementation",
        "california", "cat", "incrementation");

int maxLength = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
Set<String> results = new HashSet<>();
for (String word : wordsList) {
    int len = word.length();
    if (len >= maxLength) {
        if (len > maxLength) {
              results.clear();
              maxLength = len;
        }
        results.add(word);
    } 
}

System.out.printf("The longest word%s -> %s%n", results.size() > 1 ? "s" : "", results);
```

prints

```
The longest words -> [implementation, incrementation]
```